# Separate multipolygons into equal parts

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, splitting, multi-polygon

I am trying to separate a multipolygon into equal parts. I am aware of the divide polygon plugin and that worked well for me in previous examples where a single polygon is involved. Unfortunately I have a multipolygon with multiple parts that are not connected. When I dissolve the multipolygon it shows me only one attribute in the attribute table, so far so good. But when I try and split that up into equal parts it splits it up irregularly based on the different parts of my polygon.

Is there a way I can split that multipolygon with its different parts into equal sized sections? All I found online was focused on connected single polygons.

Comment: A screenshot could help understanding how your data looks and what you try to achieve